# Prioritizing recursive crawl in Storm Crawler

Tags: web-crawler, nutch, stormcrawler

When crawling the world wide web, I would want to give my crawler an initial seed list of URLs - and would expect my crawler to automatically  'discover' new seed URLs from internet during it's crawling.

I see such option in Apach Nutch (see topN parameter in [generate command of nutch](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch%20generate)). Is there any such option in [Storm Crawler](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler) as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StormCrawler can handle recursive crawls, and the way URLs are prioritized depends on the backend used for storing the URLs.

For instance the [Elasticsearch module](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/master/external/elasticsearch) can be used for that, see the README for a short tutorial and the [sample config file](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/es-conf.yaml), where by default the spouts will sort URLs based on their nextFetchDate (**.sort.field*).

In Nutch, the -topN argument only specifies the max number of URLs to put in the next segment (based on the scores provided by whichever scoring plugin is used). With StormCrawler we don't really need an equivalent as things are not processed by batches, the crawl runs continuously.

Comment: Instead of `nextFetchDate` can we have something like 'inboundLinkCount' or may 'linkscore'? Basically some indicator which tells 'how important the webpage is for internet'

Comment: You can use any field indexed in the status index. How you generate values for this field is a different matter. You could have an external process e.g. based on Spark to compute a PageRank value and feed that into the status index. There is no equivalent of Nutch's OPIC currently in StormCrawler but it wouldn't be too difficult to implement an 'inboundLinkCount' by writing a custom StatusUpdaterBolt (or a brand new bolt using the status stream) which would increment the value of a field in the ES index based on the outlinks (tuples with a status value of DISCOVERED)